# Is it possible to hide a website's AdMob ads in a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, admob, wkwebview

Aside from debating the ethical side of this, is it even possible? I notice a website that I use my WKWebView for has AdMob ads on the bottom. If it is possible, how would I hide these ads?

Comment: You would inject a JavaScript string via `WKWebView`'s `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) (probably inside the page load event, see `WKNavigationDelegate`). The actual JavaScript needed to disable AdMob ads you'd need to figure out.

Comment: Websites can't display AdMob ads. They're served only to apps using the AdMob mobile SDKs.

Comment: @RedBrogdon last week I watched a bunch of great tutorials by you :P I guess I got confused because the ads look really similar to my AdMob ads. If I had to guess I think it is actually an AdSense ad.. Thank you.